# Goal Seek in Octave to replicate Excel's 'Solver' Macro

Tags: octave

This is essentially a question on fundamentals, and whether or not there is a more efficient way to achieve what I am looking for. I have built a working fluid dynamics calculator in Excel to find the flow rates required for a target pressure loss, the optimisation is handled using Solver but it's very clunky and not user friendly.

I'm trying to replicate the function in Octave since it's widely used here, but I am a complete beginner; I'm probably missing something obvious. I can easily enter all of the math for a single iteration via a series of functions, but my excel file required using the 'Solver' macro, and I'm unsure how to efficiently replicate this in Octave.

I am aware that linprog (in matlab) and glpk (octave) can be used to solve systems of linear equations.

I have a series of nested equations which are all dependant on a single matrix, Q (flow rates at various locations). Many other inputs are required, but they either remain constant throughout calculation (e.g. system geometry) or are dictated by Q (e.g. Reynolds number and loss coefficients). In trying to simplify my problem I have settled on two steps:

> 1. Write code to solve my problem, input: Q matrix, output: pressure loss matrix
> 2. Create a loop that iterates different Q matrices until some conditions for the pressure loss matrix are met.

I don't think it will be practical to get my expressions into the form of A*x = B (in order to use glpk) given the complexity. **In excel, I can point solver at a Q value that drives a multitude of equations that impact pressure loss, and it will find the value I need to achieve a target. How can I most efficiently replicate this functionality in Octave?**

Answer (score 0):

First off all `Solver` is *not a macro*.  Pretty far from.

So, you're going to replicate a *comprehensive "What-If" Analysis Plug-in* -- so complex in fact, that Microsoft chose to contract a 3rd Party company of experts to develop the tool and provide support for it (successfully based on the 1.2 Billion copies they've distributed).

And you're going to this an inferior coding language that you're `a complete beginner` with?  Cool. I'd like to see this!

Cool.  Here's a **checklist** of Solver's features, so you don't miss anything:

[image: Solver Checklist]

*Good Luck!*

---

## More Information:

- Wikipedia : [Solver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solver)
- Office.com : [Define and Solve a Problem by using Solver](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040)
- Frontline: Official Solver Page:  [http://solver.com](http://solver.com/)
- AppSource.Microsoft.com : [Solver](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/office/WA104100404) (with Video)
- Frontline:L Solver International Manazine

Comment: A little bit over the top, try reading again. I can pretty much do what I want with some while loops and a criteria for how close I need to get to a target value - but it won't be very efficient. I was just curious if a goal seek functionality was included in Oracle/Matlab. It's not as though it's an uncommon procedure. Goal seeking in excel uses simple linear search, according to Microsoft themselves.